Mount an EFS on Elastic Beanstalk within a Docker Container
I am trying to deploy my django application on an elastic beanstalk environment using Docker.
This is my Dockerfile within the root of my application:

# Use bash for running commands, if available
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

# Define a default environment variable
ENV APP_ENV release

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy your application files into the Docker image
COPY . /app

# Install AWS CLI
RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y aws-cli && \
    yum install -y jq && \
    yum clean all

# Copy a script that will run your commands
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

# Run the script when the container starts
CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]

# Expose the port the app runs on
EXPOSE 8000

This is my Dockerrun.aws.json:
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "2",
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "efs-volume",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/mnt/efs"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "my-app",
      "image": "123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/iris-ai-release:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 4096,
      "privileged": true,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "efs-volume",
          "containerPath": "/mnt/efs",
          "readOnly": false
        }
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8000,
          "containerPort": 8000
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/my-app/logs",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "my-app"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


In my .platform/hooks/prebuild/00-mount-efs.sh I have this:
#!/bin/bash

# Install EFS utilities if not already installed
if ! command -v mount.efs >/dev/null; then
    echo "Installing amazon-efs-utils..."
    sudo dnf install -y amazon-efs-utils
fi

# Fetch environment variables
export "$(grep APP_ENV .env)"

# Fetch secrets from AWS Secrets Manager
APP_SECRETS=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id "my-app-$APP_ENV/$APP_ENV/secrets" --region=eu-central-1 --query=SecretString --output text)
EFS_DNS_NAME=$(echo "$APP_SECRETS" | jq -r ."EFS_DNS_NAME")
echo "EFS DNS NAME: $EFS_DNS_NAME"

# Mount EFS
EFS_MOUNT_DIR="/mnt/efs"
STATIC_DIR="${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}/static"
MEDIA_DIR="${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}/media"
RAG_STORES_DIR="${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}/rag_stores"

echo "Mounting EFS filesystem $EFS_DNS_NAME to directory $EFS_MOUNT_DIR ..."
mkdir -p ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}
mkdir -p ${STATIC_DIR}
mkdir -p ${MEDIA_DIR}
mkdir -p ${RAG_STORES_DIR}

mountpoint -q ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR} || {
    sudo mount -t efs -o tls ${EFS_DNS_NAME}:/ ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR} && \
    echo "EFS mounted at ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}" || \
    { echo "ERROR: Failed to mount EFS at ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}"; exit 1; }
}

# Adjust permissions
sudo chown -R webapp:webapp ${EFS_MOUNT_DIR}
sudo chmod 755 ${STATIC_DIR} ${MEDIA_DIR} ${RAG_STORES_DIR}


But somehow my EFS is not mounted on my Docker Container:
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-9-65 ~]$ mount | grep efs
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
127.0.0.1:/ on /mnt/efs type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,noresvport,proto=tcp,port=20792,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=127.0.0.1,local_lock=none,addr=127.0.0.1)
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-9-65 ~]$ ls -l /mnt/
total 4
drwxrwxrwx. 5 webapp webapp 6144 Apr 15 14:32 efs
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-9-65 ~]$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND            CREATED         STATUS         PORTS      NAMES
0e47b71eb563   d72065e61ebc   "/entrypoint.sh"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes   8000/tcp   wonderful_mccarthy
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-9-65 ~]$ sudo docker exec -it 0e47b71eb563 /bin/bash
bash-5.2# mount | grep efs
bash-5.2# ls -l /mnt/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 20 Apr 22 13:40 efs
bash-5.2#

As you can see I get a directory called /mnt/efs on my docker but it no mounted device as mount | grep efs shows. The files inside EC2/mnt/efs and DOCKER/mnt/efs also differ. I am trying to fix this for two weeks now and tried everything I could find. GPT4 couldn't help either. So I appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.
I tried everything. I expect to have my EFS mounted to my Docker Container.
